# Get disk space available for application on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, storage

I'm currently using Unity3D, and using C# as my main script language. My application downloads some assets from a server, and I need to make sure there is enough space available for this. My assets are going in the path that is given by Application.persistentDataPath.

I need to check this for a Mac Standalone build !

Would anyone know how to check this, preferably in Unity C#, but I can work with native code and such if I have to !

UPDATE :

Upon seeing the answer from @Marius George, I'm just wondering about a little detail : That methods gives me information on all drives. What I need is information for my app only, and not necessarily all the drives (my application might not have access to all of the disk space). Any ideas how to get the one drive I actually need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the System.IO.DriveInfo class works on some platforms:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/disk-space-available.119725/

See if this works on Mac.

Comment: Yep, that works on Mac. Something like: Debug.Log(new System.IO.DriveInfo("/").AvailableFreeSpace);

Comment: I've seen this, however it doesn't appear to work in the Unity3D editor as it says "NotImplementedException:The requested feature is not implemented". Would it work in a standalone build for Mac ?

Comment: Did you try the ("/") option as shown by Khakionion? Maybe that works on the current drive on which your application is installed.

Comment: I did try that, however I'm not sure the values returned are right... Somehow the AvailableFreeSpace is higher than the TotalFreeSpace, and even higher than the TotalSize... and the values are not right according to what I'm seeing on my test device. Maybe I'm getting something wrong ? (The value returned is in bits, correct? I've doubled checked with bits and bytes conversions and it doesn't seem to be right in either case)

Comment: Just checked (don't know why I missed it before), the returned value is in bytes. However, the values are still wrong somehow. Maybe I'm missing something obvious about hard drives ?

Comment: Created another question for this new problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252100/system-io-driveinfo-returns-wrong-disk-space-values , I'll accept your answer but would appreciate it if you guys could take a look at it ! Thanks again.

Comment: No one has answered further on my last question, updated a couple things. Would appreciate some input from you guys :)

Comment: I was digging around a bit regarding bugs in the implementation of DriveInfo on some platforms, and found some posts a few years old. Nothing else came up that is very recent.